# How to improve performance of MongoDB distinct query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection named `food` with documents like this:

```json
{
    _id: 123,
    vegetables: [
      {
        size: small
      }
    ]
}
```

I have also created an index to help optimise the query I created: `db.food.createIndex({"vegetables.size": 1}, "sorted_vegetables");`

Multiple different `food` documents may have various `vegetables` with the same size. I am trying to create a query to get all unique vegetables sizes across all documents. This is what I got: `db.food.distinct("vegetables.size")`.

The problem I am having is how bad the performance for this is, even with the index. Take a look at the query planner and execution stats for the query:

```json
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "db.food",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "AGGREGATE",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "DISTINCT",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXONLYSCAN",
                        "indexName" : "sorted_vegetables",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "executionTimeMillis" : "9067.624",
        "planningTimeMillis" : "0.163",
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "AGGREGATE",
            "nReturned" : "1",
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : "9061.913",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "DISTINCT",
                "nReturned" : "2127",
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : "9060.694",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "nReturned" : "1185523",
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : "8788.255",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXONLYSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : "1185523",
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : "1185.879",
                        "indexName" : "sorted_vegetables",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongo-instance",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.0"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The DB has a little more than 1 million documents. However, 9 seconds is an extremely long time, especially when the same query without an index takes around the same time. It doesn't seem like the index is helping at all